# No fallback instance of type class kotlin.Unit found for feign client

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, microservices, jhipster

I'm trying to consume a microservices as a feign client but I getting this error.

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.claro.mcp.client.McpUaaClient'
: FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No fallback instance of type class kotlin.Unit found for feign client mcpuaa

Error creating bean with name 'com.claro.mcp.client.McpUaaClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No fallback instance of type class kotlin.Unit found for feign client mcpuaa
```

I'm using Kotlin 1.3.40 and Spring Boot 2.1.6. RELEASE. My project is based on [Khipster code generator](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-kotlin)

This is my feign client

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "mcpuaa")
public interface McpUaaClient {
    @PostMapping("/api/auth/validatePassword")
    ResponseEntity<JsonObject> validatePassword(String password);
}
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, I only had to implement a fallback for my feign client. Since Kotlin does not support primitive types, in this case "void", which is a type allowed for spring cloud to avoid implement a fallback, I was force to create an implementation to handle this scenario.